# Realloc initially works, then returns null after several repetitions

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

Realloc initially works for array sizes 200 and 400, but then unexpectedly returns null at size 800 for reasons I cannot parse.

Unsigned long ints in use because of that massive m value and are very much necessary. Probably.

I'm embarrassingly bad at C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

/* Macros */
#define m    4294967161
#define a    2
#define r    (m % a)
#define q    (unsigned long) floor(m / a)

/* Method stubs */
[snip]

/* Initial array settings */
unsigned long elements = 0;   // Number of elements in the array.
unsigned long size = 100;     // Dynamically allocated size of the array.

/* Evaluates g(x) = ax mod m with no values > m - 1 */
unsigned long g(unsigned long x) {
    [snip]
}

unsigned long compute() {
    unsigned long i = 1;
    unsigned long x = a;
    unsigned long j = 0;
    unsigned long *multipliers = 0;
    initialize(&multipliers);

    while (x != 1) {
        if (((m % x) < (m / x)) && (gcd(i, m - 1) == 1)) {
            add(x, multipliers);
            j++;
        }
        i++;
        x = g(x);
    }
}

/* Initialize array. */
void initialize(unsigned long **multipliers) {
    *multipliers = (unsigned long *)malloc(sizeof(unsigned long) * size);
}

/* Add element to an array. */
void add(unsigned long element, unsigned long *multipliers) {
    if (elements >= size) {
        printf("Inside elements >= size check.\n");
        size = size * 2;
        printf("Size is now %lu\n", size);
        unsigned long *n_vector = NULL;
        n_vector = (unsigned long *)realloc(multipliers, sizeof(unsigned long) * size);
        printf("Reallocated.\n");

        if (n_vector != NULL) {
            printf("Copying n_vector to multipliers.\n");
            multipliers = n_vector;
        }
        else
            printf("n_vector is null.\n");
    }
    multipliers[elements++] = element;
    return;
}
```

Comment: And what was the output of `printf("Size is now %lu\n", size);` and other `printf()`?

Comment: With `m` and `a` being (unsigned) integers, `m / a` is always 'floored' (technically truncated, but with them always positive it's equivalent to flooring), so using `floor` and the cast aren't necessary. Also: no need to [cast the result of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/249237) or `realloc`.

Comment: `q`, as `#define q    (unsigned long) floor(m / a)` is scary.  Although not used in posted code, I would use `#define q   ((unsigned long) floor(m / a))` to prevent unexpected precedence rule effects.

Comment: When reallocating, you need a pointer to pointer. (multipliers is a pointer) The initialise function does this correct. Since you already have a global pointer, it is maybe better *not* to pass (a pointer to) it as a argument to the resize function?

Comment: @wildplasser Nice. `multipliers` in `add(x, multipliers);` is not updated.

Comment: BTW: The argument shadows the global name, too. Just removing the argument from the function "signature" would possibly make things work.

Comment: i guess you want to have `elements` and `size` and the array inside of a `struct`. otherwise it doesn't make sense to just pass the array around while having its related data to be global.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the problematic part of your code:

> ```
> void add(unsigned long element, unsigned long *multipliers) {
>         n_vector = realloc(multipliers, sizeof(unsigned long) * size);
>         multipliers = n_vector;
> }
> ```

On entry, `multipliers` is a pointer to a buffer allocated by `malloc`. You call `realloc`, which returns the new address of the buffer. The new address may or may not be equal to the old one. You then set the **local** variable `multipliers` to the new address. But that's a local variable. When the function returns, the new address is not stored anywhere. The caller of this function (the `compute` function) is still using the old address.

After the first call to `realloc` that changes the address, you might initially not notice anything, because the old address still has the old content; but when you write past the old end, you're potentially overwriting data structures used by the memory management system. At the point where you call `realloc` again, the parameter that you pass to it is the address of the old buffer, which, at this point, no longer points to a buffer that `malloc`/`realloc` are managing. At this point, all hell breaks loose.

Solution: `add` needs to return the new address to its caller. Either make it return it (you can since it's currently returning nothing), or pass the `multipliers` pointer to it as a reference rather than a value — in other words, in C, make the argument a pointer to a pointer. Here are the main relevant lines in the second approach:

```
void add(unsigned long element, unsigned long **multipliers) {
    …
    n_vector = realloc(*multipliers, sizeof(unsigned long) * size);
    if (n_vector == NULL) {
        … // error handling
    } else {
        *multipliers = n_vector;
    }
}

void compute() {
     …
     add(x, &multipliers);
     …
}
```